# Retrieve select option value in webform-mail.tpl.php (7.x-4.x-dev)

Tags: theming, webforms

I have a custom mail template in Webform so values can be in a table for copying/pasting into Excel.

I want the value of the select option fields instead of the key (doing manual entry for webform creators would be too tedious). I can't seem to get to those values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my current code for webform-mail.tpl.php:

```
<h2>
<?php
    print $node->title;
?>
</h2>

<?php print ($email['html'] ? '<p>' : '') . t('Submitted on [submission:date:long]'). ($email['html'] ? '</p>' : ''); ?>

<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
<?php
foreach ($node->webform['components'] as $key => $component) {
    if (isset($submission->data[$key][0])) {
   $key_converted = ucwords(str_replace('_',' ', $node->webform['components'][$key]['form_key']));
    print '<tr><td style="border: 1px solid black;">'. $key_converted .'<td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . ($submission->data[$key][0]) . "</td></tr>";
}
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that runs across this:

```
<h2>
<?php
print $node->title;
?>
</h2>

<?php print ($email['html'] ? '<p>' : '') . t('Submitted on [submission:date:long]'). ($email['html'] ? '</p>' : ''); ?>


<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
<?php
foreach ($node->webform['components'] as $key => $component) {
   if (isset($submission->data[$key][0])) {
     $key_converted = ucwords(str_replace('_',' ', $node->webform['components'][$key]['form_key']));
     $submittedvalue = $submission->data[$key][0];

     if (isset($submittedvalue)) {
       print '<tr><td style="border: 1px solid black;">'. $key_converted .'</td><td style="border: 1px solid black;">';
       if ($node->webform['components'][$key]['type'] != "select") {
           print $submittedvalue;
       }
       else {
        $selectlistitems = explode("|", $node->webform['components'][$key]['extra']['items']);
        if (is_numeric($submittedvalue)) {
                print $selectlistitems[$submittedvalue];
        }
        else {
                 print $submittedvalue;
        }
       }
       print '</td></tr>';
       }
  }
}
?>
</table>
```